# How do you turn a .gif into a byte[][]?

Tags: java, arrays

I am using an API that has a method

```
public void setImage(byte[][] newImage)
```

The only information given to be in the API Reference is

"The format of this image is a simple raw `2D array` of bytes. Every byte represents shade of gray from `black (0)` to `white (255)`. When indexing the `2D array`, `Y axis` goes first, `X axis` goes second, e.g. image[y][x].
Parameter value is not cloned internally. To avoid unwanted sharing, clone the image data before calling this method."

I am supposed to be passing a .gif image to this method but can not figure out for the life of me how to turn a .gif into a `byte[][] array`.

Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like homework. Please tag it as such. Edit: ...or leave it as it is.

Comment: Did you already manage to read the image?

Comment: @f1sh: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: There's a fundimental problem with the API that declared the `setImage` method. A `byte` in Java is signed and therefore represents a minimum of -128 and a maximum value of 127, so cannot be used to values 0 - 255.

Answer (score 2):

There's various ways to convert color to grayscale but the simplest is to average the red, grean and blue values like this:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File([your gif]));

int[][] imageBytes = new int[image.getHeight()][image.getWidth()];

for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) 
{
  for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) 
  {
    Color color = new Color(image.getRGB(x, y));
    imageBytes[y][x] = (color.getRed() + color.getGreen() + color.getBlue()) / 3;
  }
}
```

Note, I have used an `int` array because (as I previously commented) there's a fundimental problem with the API that declared the `setImage` method. A `byte` in Java is signed and therefore represents a minimum of -128 and a maximum value of 127, so cannot be used to values 0 - 255.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using standard image io, you could do the following:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( <your image file> );
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();

int width=image.getWidth(null);
int height=image.getHeight(null);
BufferedImage bi=new BufferedImage(width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);
bi.getGraphics().drawImage(image,0,0,null);
ImageIO.write(bi,"RAW",baos);

baos.flush();
byte[] resultImageAsRawBytes = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();
```

What this basically does is: it reads the image into a `BufferedImage`, renders it into a grayscale images and writes the result to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` which allows you to access the raw bytes.

A few notes though: 
- You'd need to add exception handling yourself
- I'm not 100% sure about the `"RAW"` format (unfortunately I couldn't test it myself), but it should get you started

As an alternative, you can get the image's raster, e.g. by calling `image.getRaster()`, iterate over the pixels yourself, convert them to unsigned bytes and put them into the byte array.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is that a .gif file does not store the image data as simple as a bitmap does, a gif's content is a defined structure and the image data is encoded with LZW.

That means that reading a gif file and extracting the image data is not trivial.

You can try to use [gif4j](http://www.gif4j.com) which lets you read gif files, where you can then [access each Pixel](http://www.gif4j.com/java-api-pro/com/gif4j/GifFrame.html#getX%28%29). Using a simple loop you can then create your two-dimensional array.