# How can i convert gif to byte array and byte array to gif image in JavaME?

Tags: java, java-me, gif, bufferedimage

I have byte array of gif image and i'm using something like this

```
import javax.microedition.lcdui.Image;
 byte[] picBytes = (byte[])obj;
Image.createImage(picBytes, 0, picBytes.length));
```

I want to show image on

```
javax.microedition.lcdui.Form;
```

this is working fine for JPEG and PNG images but when i try to convert 
GIF image using this logic my GIF image is looks like PNG or JPEG image,
no animation remain in GIF. please help me.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you turn a .gif into a byte\[\]\[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17951396/how-do-you-turn-a-gif-into-a-byte)

Comment: @MS90 thanks for reply, i have check that but i have opposite issue and i'm working on JavaME.

Comment: I have updated my question please check :)

Comment: A Gif animation is not natively supported on Java ME. Can you create a PNG with all frames and use a https://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/game/Sprite.html ?

Comment: Thank you **@TelmoPimentelMota** , For instruction that Java ME not support GIF animation. I'm new to Java ME. I have checked URL given by you but at current i have byte array of GIF image where 2 or 3 images are compressed together and creating GIF image. I am using java server who sends images to Java ME midlet then midlet show image on Form. (PNG and JPEG showing perfectly )